# How do I update a specific document from a form through mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Struggling with this problem because I'm missing some fundamentals I think, but after hours looking through the docs I think I need some help :)

I have a (simplified) collection as so:

```
const ExampleSchema= new Schema ({
    Word: String,
    Difficulty: String,
)};
```

Which I am succesfully displaying on a page as so:

```
<% ExampleSchemas.forEach(exampleschema=> { %>      
<p><%= exampleschema.word %></p>
<p style="display: none" name="ExampleSchemaID" value="<%= ExampleSchema._id %>"</p>
<% }) %>
```

For each word I have a form below, I would like the user to be able to select `easy`, `ok` or `hard` and for this to set the value in the DB.

```
<form method="PUT">     
    <button formaction="/review/feedback/easy">Easy</button> 
    <button formaction="/review/feedback/ok">Ok</button>
    <button formaction="/review/feedback/hard">Hard</button>
/form>
```

I have played around with a route like this to no avail

```
    router.put("/review/feedback/easy", function (req,res){
        var ID = req.body.ExampleSchemaID;
ExampleSchema.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.ExampleSchema._id,
        req.Difficulty= easy);
```

The further issue is that I would like to display `x` number of these documents to the user, therefore I need a route that gets only that specific word.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.put("/review/feedback/easy", function (req,res){
        var ID = req.body.ExampleSchemaID;
ExampleSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.ExampleSchema._id},{"Difficulty": "3"});
```

but please not your difficulty is a number, so why not use a number instead:

```
const ExampleSchema= new Schema ({
    Word: String,
    Difficulty: Number,
)}; 

router.put("/review/feedback/easy", function (req,res){
            var ID = req.body.ExampleSchemaID;
    ExampleSchema.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id": req.params.ExampleSchema._id},{"Difficulty": 3});
```

Comment: I edited the post to change it from '3' to 'easy' - thanks for spotting. This still doesn't work though